# Inside Ansible Playbook call another .yml file

Tags: ansible

I need to execute another Ansible playbook `.yml` file when I'm inside, let say, `master.yml` file.
Is that possible? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Inside you master.yml provide as below.

```
- name: call the slave playbook
  include_tasks: slave.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionally you are looking for is called [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html)